# How to stop the Cygwin terminal from forgetting the environment when opening it in a non-home folder?

Tags: cygwin, ocaml

I got [Ocaml for Windows](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/) which comes prepackaged with Cygwin. Since I wanted to be able to open `mintty` from the command line in the current directory, so I added it to PATH and then just running `mintty` does the trick. While this causes it to open in the current directory the problem is that when I run any of the Ocaml executables like `opam` I get an error.

```
Marko@Lain /cygdrive/e/Webdev/Ocaml/todolist
$ opam
bash: opam: command not found
```

When I run it using `mintty -` like the shortcut does, this in fact works.

```
Marko@Lain ~
$ cd "E:\Webdev\Ocaml\todolist"

Marko@Lain /cygdrive/e/Webdev/Ocaml/todolist
$ opam
usage: opam [--version]
            [--help]
            <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used opam commands are:
    init         Initialize opam state, or set init options.
    list         Display the list of available packages.
    show         Display information about specific packages.
    install      Install a list of packages.
    remove       Remove a list of packages.
    update       Update the list of available packages.
    upgrade      Upgrade the installed package to latest version.
    config       Display configuration options for packages.
    repository   Manage opam repositories.
    switch       Manage multiple installation prefixes.
    pin          Pin a given package to a specific version or source.
    admin        Tools for repository administrators

See 'opam help <command>' for more information on a specific command.
```

What do I have to do so that I get this behavior normally?

Also, since `mintty` runs a terminal in a standalone window, it would be better to run `bash`, but `bash -` does not work for me. After I get this to work, I'd like to add `bash` to my list of VS Code shells and for that I'd need to understand how to run it in an arbitrary directory from the command line while keeping its memory of the home environment.

Answer (score 1):

This command `mintty -` start your shell as login one. 
If you run a not-login shell, most of the configuration script are not read, and enviroment is taken from the father process, but of course your link fails as Windows can not provide a proper one.
If you want to be able to open a `login shell` from explorer the best way is to install `chere` package

```
$ chere -h
/usr/bin/chere version 1.4

Usage:
/usr/bin/chere -<iuxlrhv> [-lracnmpf12] [-t <term>] [-s <shell>]
        [-d <display> ] [-o <options>] [-e <menutext>]

Adds the stated terminal/shell combination to the folder context menu
This allows you to right click a folder in Windows Explorer and open
a Cygwin shell in that folder.

Options:
  i - Install
  u - Uninstall
  x - Freshen eXisting entries
  l - List currently installed chere items
  r - Read all chere registry entries to stdout
  a - All users
  c - Current user only
  n - Be Nice and provide Control Panel uninstall option (Default)
  m - Minimal, no Control Panel uninstall
  p - Print regtool commands to stdout rather than running them
  f - Force write (overwrite existing, ignore missing files)
  1 - Start using registry one-liners. This doesn't work with ash,
      tcsh or network shares.
  2 - Start via bash script. Relies on windows to change directory,
      and login scripts avoiding doing a cd /home/Marco 
  h - Help
  v - Version

  t <term> - Use terminal term. Supported terminals are:
        cmd rxvt mintty xterm urxvt

  s <shell> - Use the named shell. Supported shells are:
        ash bash cmd dash fish mksh pdksh posh tcsh zsh passwd

  d <display> - DISPLAY to use (xterm, urxvt). Defaults to :0.
      Set to env to use the runtime environment variable.

  o <options> - Add <options> to the terminal startup command.
      If more than one option is specified, they should all be
      contained within a single set of quotes.

  e <menutext> - Use <menutext> as the context menu text.

See the man page for more detail.
```

You can than install your preferred or default shell on explorer `right click` menu as an additional item. It will open a `login shell` in the chosen directory.

[image]